# Vertex color in Blender

Tags: blender

I don't know why "COL"  appears in DATA TAB as shown on the picture added to my post. I didn't vertex paint my model. I only added color through material tab. 
Can I delete it? 
Why does it appear? [image]

Comment: In case you imported the model, it may have had a color per vertex assigned. You don't really need it unless you use it in your shaders.

Comment: Thanks! I didn't import it. I did it myself. I will delete it. Thank you.